# How to distinguish between applied forces and forces of constraint?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, constrained-dynamics

Is there any generic prescription to separate the set of applied forces  to the set of forces of constraint with respect to any arbitrary physical system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking about classical forces, I can think about a couple of simple tests.

1) Cause and effect or sequence. Naturally, an applied force has to precede a constraining force.

2) Energy source. Whether applied and constraining forces are in balance or not, there are always some potential or kinetic energy changes, associated with the forces. The applied force is always the source of that energy. Of course, the source of energy can always be traced back to sun, big bang, etc., so this test is applicable to this particular interaction only.